# Interpreting NSURLConnection responses: NSError

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperation, nserror

I am setting up a NSURLConnection which send an asynchrounous request and deals with it using a completionHandler.

```
__block int errorType = 0; //server error code: 200, 300 etc..
__block BOOL hasError = FALSE;
__block NSDictionary *json;

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] 
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)   {

                           // HERE I WOULD LIKE TO INTERPRET connectionError
                           // AND SET IF IT HASERROR OR NOT as well as the error type

                           json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                  options:0
                                                                    error:nil];



                       }];
```

Based on the error type I would need to do different things. The only issue is that I do not know how to interpret the error in this context.

I need to extract information like: "the request was not sent", "the request was sent".

Any suggestion / reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
connectionError.localizedDescription
```

There is useful article about [NSError](http://nshipster.com/nserror/)

In case if there is no error connectionError object will be nil.

Comment: Thanks, I was reading the article and ad some point I saw that the author was referencing directly to the "connectionError" variable in this way "if(connectionError){...}". I am unsure about this as connectionError is a NSError object and I do not understand how the if can work as it is not a boolean and there is no check against "nil" values. I am probably just too much of a newbie in this :)

Comment: `if(connectionError)(...)` is the same as `if(nil == connectionError)`.